# How to do 3 operations without rendering 3 times?

Tags: windows

How to do 3 operations without rendering 3 times?

I want to do three filter operations in *ffmpeg*, but without encoding three times: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.959]

1. Video crop
2. Add cropped video over image
3. Add text to result video

The operations visualized:

[image: i want...(image)]

My current code (working but 3x render):

```
ffmpeg -i kare.mp4 -filter:v "crop=in_w:in_h-472" -c:a copy kirp.mp4 && ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i kirp.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[V1]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1080:608[V2]; [V1][V2]overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=600" sablon.mp4  && ffmpeg -i sablon.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Be.ttf:text='123asd':fontcolor=white:fontsize=105:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/3.8" -codec:a copy output.mp4 && del "kirp.mp4" del "sablon.mp4"
```

Comment: Did you google the error message? It is probably caused because `'` needed to be escaped with `\"` (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59788692)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just chaining the filters together? Something like this should work:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i kare.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];[1:v]crop=in_w:in_h-472, \
setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1080:608[s3]; \
[s0][s3]overlay=eof_action=repeat:shortest=1:x=0:y=600, \
drawtext=fontcolor=white:fontfile=Be.ttf:fontsize=105: \
text='(MyText)':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/3.8[s5]" \
-map "[s5]" -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

**Edit:** Since you're on Windows, try this (no modifications to it are needed):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i kare.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];[1:v]crop=in_w:in_h-472,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1080:608[s3];[s0][s3]overlay=eof_action=repeat:shortest=1:x=0:y=600,drawtext=fontcolor=white:fontfile=Be.ttf:fontsize=105:text='(MyText)':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/3.8[s5]" -map "[s5]" -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 with the latest versions of FFmpeg respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but unfortunately it didn't work [AVFilterGraph @ 00000288901af540] No such filter: '\'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: @emreya You do not specify what OS and shell you’re using. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: sorry i didn't know there was a difference by operating system

Comment: edited code : ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i kare.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];[1:v]crop=in_w:in_h-472[s1];[s1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s2];[s2]scale=1080:608[s3];[s0][s3]overlay=eof_action=repeat:shortest=1:x=0:y=600[s4];[s4]drawtext=fontcolor=white:fontfile=Be.ttf:fontsize=105:text='(MyText)':x=(w-text_w)\2:y=(h-text_h)\3.8[s5]" -map [s5] -map 1:a -acodec copy output.mp4

Comment: result :   [Parsed_drawtext_5 @ 000002dd778b52c0] [Eval @ 000000f0895fe6f0] Invalid chars '2' at the end of expression '(w-text_w)2'
[Parsed_drawtext_5 @ 000002dd778b52c0] Failed to parse expression: (w-text_w)2
[Parsed_drawtext_5 @ 000002dd778b52c0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawtext_5
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: @emreya That error states that you removed a forward slash `/` from the expression `(w-text_w)/2`.

Comment: You seem to have changed the slash to a backslash?

Comment: @pigeonburger No need for a link label after each filter. Can be simplified by creating [filterchains](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1): `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i kare.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[s0];[1:v]crop=in_w:in_h-472,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1080:608[s3];[s0][s3]overlay=eof_action=repeat:shortest=1:x=0:y=600,drawtext=fontcolor=white:fontfile=Be.ttf:fontsize=105:text='(MyText)':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/3.8[s5]" -map "[s5]" -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan Thanks, I'll update my answer - it's an old habit from developing a program that used more complicated filters :)

Comment: @pigeonburger the last code you added worked great and I am very happy, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in the second step you are taking the cropped video, scaling it, and then putting it on **top** of the image. I am not checking whether all the other values used by you fit your requirements. Anyhow, what will work in that case is:

```
ffmpeg -i kare.mp4 -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]anull[audio]; \
[0:v]crop=in_w:in_h-472[cropped];[cropped]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[V1]; \
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1080:608[V2]; \
[V1][V2]overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=600[overlaid]; \
[overlaid]drawtext=fontfile=Be.ttf:text='(MyText)':fontcolor=white: \
fontsize=105:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/3.8[videout]" -map [videout] \
-map [audio] -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Here the first chain in the filtergraph just passes the audio without tampering. The second part does the cropping of the video (first input stream 0). The third part sets PTS (presentation time stamp). The fourth part sets the PTS for the second input which is the image and scales it. (**Is this what you want?**)

The fifth part overlays the image on top of the cropped video. If you want the video on top of the image, you will have to reverse the order of `[v1][v2]` before overlay filter. In the overlay filter the second pad always goes on top.

The sixth part draws the text on top of this composite. On my system my font settings are different, but essentially this format will work.

Tested on bash 4.4 and ffmpeg 4.4.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but unfortunately it didn't work [AVFilterGraph @ 0000015c83a3c200] No such filter: '\'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: @emreya As stated in the answer "tested on bash 4.4". You didn't mention your OS, so you're probably using Windows. The backslashes for the line breaks won't work for you. Remove the backslashes at the end of each line and make the command 1 long line, or replace the backslashes with a caret (`^`).

Comment: yes windows, very thanx, edited code result  :  Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> crop
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> anull
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> setpts
  drawtext -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  anull -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000001ec20111e00] [swscaler @ 000001ec2011edc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001ec20111e00] [swscaler @ 000001ec20193f40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly ....

Comment: [Parsed_drawtext_6 @ 000001ec200ff280] [Eval @ 00000027369fe260] Invalid chars '2' at the end of expression '(w-text_w)2'
[Parsed_drawtext_6 @ 000001ec200ff280] Failed to parse expression: (w-text_w)2
[Parsed_drawtext_6 @ 000001ec200ff280] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawtext_6
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: In Windows you need to provide full path to font file with forward slashes denoting what is normally shown as backslashes in windows.

Comment: `"drawtext=fontfile= /windows/fonts/font.ttf:text='(MyText)':fontcolor=white:fontsize=10:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2"`  And you seem to have missed the divided by forward slash after the bracket portion.